# Is there a way to delete the picture on hangouts so they cant see it? retrieve picture

Tags: images, google-hangouts, delete, picture-frame-widget

I wanted to recall a photo, that I sent to someone by accident. They are out of town, so I know they haven't seen it yet. Is there any way to delete the picture on hangouts so they can't see it?

Comment: a-lo: Apparently this is a popular post. Did the answer work for you? If so, please select the checkmark on the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

[Share and delete your photos from Hangouts messages and Google Voice MMS](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115410?hl=en):

> You can delete photos that you sent through a Hangouts message or
>   through a Google Voice multimedia message in Hangouts. You'll need to
>   delete the photos from Picasa Web Albums.
>
> Even if you delete a photo in your Picasa album, if you sent it
>   through a multimedia message, the person who received it may still
>   have a copy of the image on their device.
>
> 1. Go to [Picasa Web Albums](https://picasaweb.google.com/home).
> 2. Click Show All Albums. If you're using Hangouts to send Google Voice multimedia messages, make sure you're going to the Picasa
>      account that is connected to the Google Voice account.
> 3. Click the album with the photos you want to delete. For Hangouts users: The photo album's title will be the name of the person you had
>      the Hangout with. For Google Voice users: The photo album's title will
>      be the phone number of the person who received the photo.
> 4. Click the photo that you want to delete.
> 5. Click Actions > Delete this photo. If you want to delete the entire album, open the album and click Actions > Delete album.

Comment: So after deleting from.google photos, it would be recalled?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as of november 2016

Comment: April 2017 -- this worked for me.  It was very tedious, because the hangout in question had about 1000 photos in it, and there didn't seem to be any way to jump to the end, so I had to scroll a lot.  And then when I deleted it, the thumbnail remained; but I convinced myself that the image was mostly gone by logging in with a different browser, opening Hangouts, and noting that the image had been replaced with a bar-in-a-circle icon.

Comment: The newer version of the link for Picasa Web Albums seems to be: https://get.google.com/albumarchive/    There I had an album titled "Photos from Hangouts" in which separate chats albums are present.

Comment: It's easier to delete the album at get.google.com/albumarchive that @macieksk gave. No need to scroll through the Hangout like user:offby1 did. My photos remained in Google Photos, but were removed from my Hangout and the other party's hangout, and replaced by a red no photo "!" thumbnail. When you go to delete the conversation, Google will give the get.google.com/albumarchive link to delete photos. If you don't delete photos, then delete the conversation, I think the photos remain if the other party still has the conversation.